# Finite State Automaton implementation

Tags: php, state

I've been studying compiler construction theory. Right now, I'm studying [Finite State Automaton](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Compiler_Construction/Lexical_analysis#Finite_State_Automaton) and I've tried to create my own implementation. I'm not sure if my implementation is right.

[image: State machine transition diagram]

```
<?php
/**
 * FINITE STATE AUTOMATON
 * ======================
 * - states
 * - starting state
 * - accept state
 * - transition table
 *
 * Input string examples:
 * 10112 - Accepted
 * 222 - Rejected
 *
 * Diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkcIq.png
 */
$s1 = 'S1';
$s2 = 'S2';

$states = [];
$starting_state = $s1;

$transition_table = [
    'S1' => [
        '2' => 'S3',
        '1' => 'S1',
        '0' => 'S2',
    ],
    'S2' => [
        '1' => 'S1',
        '0' => 'S2',
    ],
    'S3' => [],
];
$input_string = '10112';

$current_state = $starting_state;
foreach (str_split($input_string) as $character) {
    if (isset($transition_table[$current_state][$character])) {
        $current_state = $transition_table[$current_state][$character];
        $states[] = $current_state;
    }
}
if (count($states) == strlen($input_string)) {
    echo 'Accepted';
} else {
    echo 'Rejected';
}
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Did I get the whole idea? Are there something that I've missed?

Is this FSA thing related to regular expressions? It seems to be similar.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite good, I especially like the `$current_state` explanatory variable. Actually, I'd create another one to remove some duplication:

```
$transitions = $transition_table[$current_state];
if (isset($transitions[$character])) {
    $current_state = $transitions[$character];
    $states[] = $current_state;
}
```

Some other notes:

1. The code currently ignores invalid transitions. You could break the loop immediately if a transition is invalid:

   ```
   foreach (str_split($input_string) as $character) {
       $transitions = $transition_table[$current_state];
       if (isset($transitions[$character])) {
           $current_state = $transitions[$character];
           $states[] = $current_state;
       } else {
           break;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Inverting the isset would make the code [flatten](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html) a little bit:

   ```
   foreach (str_split($input_string) as $character) {
       $transitions = $transition_table[$current_state];
       if (!isset($transitions[$character])) {
           break;
       }
       $current_state = $transitions[$character];
       $states[] = $current_state;
   }
   ```
3. `$s2` is unused, I guess you could remove it:

   > ```
   > $s2 = 'S2';
   > ```
4. > Are there something that I've missed?

   The linked page mentions classes and I guess it should have been an object oriented solution. Check [the Wikipedia article about the Java implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern#Java), it shows a great example.